Angular PWA ngsw-worker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at ngsw-worker.js:1:1)
Using Angular V14.2.
Getting the below error in the console window.

In the Application tab -> service workers menu the status is not getting activated.

App.module.ts file


What is the content of the ngsw file downloaded from server? I guess it is the content of 404 because of miss configuration of output and missing file on server

content type in the response headers is "application/javascript".
Where to add the missed configurration @ThomasRenger ?

it did not download any content from the server. The error message shown like "Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found" on the network tab

In my case, the generated ngsw-worker.js file compressed with brotli. So the content of the ng-sw-worker.js file got encoded.
So the browser could not able to execute the encoded content after the deployment.
I just excluded the ngsw-worker.js file from the "brotli"(or G-Zip) compression. It works as expected.
